How to Fix INVALID_ARGUMENT Error When Deploying App Engine with --no-cache Option?
I’m trying to deploy my application to Google App Engine using the gcloud command-line tool with the --no-cache option. However, I’m encountering an error related to the beta_settings in my configuration file.
Command I’m Using:
gcloud app deploy dev_app_config.yaml --no-cache --version=1

Error Message:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unrecognized or permitted keys in configuration beta_settings
fieldViolations:
-descriptions: Unrecognized beta_settings keys
    field: no-cache


Do you have no-cache in your yaml file? If you do, then remove it and deploy again with the --no-cache flag (same command you ran before)

I tried recreating this and I also encountered the same error. It seems like it is working with Standard environment but having problems with Flexible. Have you tried removing "no-cache" in your yaml file and "--no-cache" in your command?
